# Included layout missing on Android API 21

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have an app that has been running on my deivce perfectly fine for a long time. Today I decided to test it on an older device. I have an old Glaxy S4 Mini, so I loaded it up, and an entire part of my layout was missing. The missing part is a reusable layout I made, and included it in this activity. The space where it would be is not taken up by anything, it is just left empty

This is the activity layout file. Everything that is inside of `include` is completely missing when the app is ran.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.eddie.songsPrimirenya.SearchActivityReg">

    <include
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:id="@+id/search_bar_include"
        layout="@layout/search_bar"
        />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/RecyclerViewReg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/search_bar_include"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is the layout that I was including earlier. I think it's not showing because of some compatibility issue, but I do not know what it is.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/cardSearchReg"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        card_view:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        card_view:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/LayoutAll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/LayoutSearch"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/txtInReg"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:hint="@string/search"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/textHint" />


            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/LayoutSearchModeSelect"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/LayoutSearch"
                android:layout_marginStart="3dp">

                <Switch
                    android:id="@+id/swtSearchType"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="false"
                    android:text="@string/search_by_name"
                    android:textColorHighlight="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is an image of how it is supposed to look like
[image]

and this is what it ends up looking like
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make your include layout match parent,it should work fine

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.eddie.songsPrimirenya.SearchActivityReg">

    <include
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:id="@+id/search_bar_include"
        layout="@layout/search_bar"
        />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/RecyclerViewReg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/search_bar_include"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you, it works? Why is that necessary for an older device, but not a newer one?